# Not able to use bower from corporate proxy server, how fix?

Tags: node.js, proxy, bower, bower-install

I am trying to install the bower using my office proxy server. I got error. Then I tried to install in my 'C' drive. It was installed but I got numerous 304 status.

Later I tried to search backbone using bower, this time I got the issue like this: how to fix this and what is the issue with my network proxy or admin rights or etc?

here is the error I am getting:

```
C:\Bower>bower search backbone
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/backb
one failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 1.1s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/backb
one failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 2.6s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/backb
one failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 5.3s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/backb
one failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 8.4s
bower retry         Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/backb
one failed with ETIMEDOUT, retrying in 27.0s
bower ETIMEDOUT     Request to https://bower.herokuapp.com/packages/search/backb
one failed: connect ETIMEDOUT
```

how to fix this issue? any one help me

Answer (score 1):

Create `.bowerrc` file in your home dir with this caption:

```
{
  "directory": "library",
  "registry": "http://bower.herokuapp.com",
  "proxy":"<YOUR_PROXY>",
  "https-proxy":"<YOUR_HTTPS_PROXY>"
}
```